# "show tables" or "describe" in FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I was curious to know if there is a way to problematically get s list of all the FQL tables, a list of all their columns and which columns are index-able. I can't find anything in the documentation short of following the docs to create data objects defining these details for each FQL table.

Comment: To my knowledge, there's not. But i'm not listing this as an answer because i'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I haven't tried myself, but this seems to do exactly what you've asked for.

https://github.com/jwerle/fql-workbench/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't exists, however, Facebook has a complete reference about available tables, with all their respective columns and column data types:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement a show-tables or describe functionality in FQL using the tables 'column' and 'table'. This is what https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/ says about it:

column - An FQL table that documents columns in other FQL tables
table - An FQL table containing information about other FQL tables

We can query these tables using FQL to find out the schema of the regular tables.